# Does releasing a new version of the app delete files of the older one?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I'm gonna release a new version of my app. The previous version used some files which in the newer version are changed and need to be processed. I want the older files to be automatically deleted when the user updates the application, otherwise the application sees them and will process them (resulting in an error because the format of the files changed).
Is there an option to do that?

Thank you.

Comment: I also wanted to note that the algorithm is basically this: 1) If files are not there, download them 2) Process files. The problem is that I cannot replace older files because I need to download them from the internet. So how can I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are processing these files, one option is to somehow put the format version in the files or in folder path.  Bake that version into a constant in the app.

The app can either always look for those files by appending the constants to the path where you get these files, or look into the data of the file to get the format version and handle it properly (delete, redownload etc...).

Another benefit is that if you release your app and the format version does not change (likely - you just fixed bugs), you don't have to delete and re-download those files.  You also don't have to change anything or update any routines - simply don't change the file format constant and it won't change your files.  If you change the format of the files, update that constant and it just works.

Comment: I like this method, but I tend to put the version of the data as a variable in the data file itself, this way I only have to search for one file name.

Comment: @Javy: The downside to using the app version is your version always changes - only redownload if the file format version changes, not the app version.

Comment: I don't follow. The version stays the same (the bundle version).  A check is made on launch to ensure the version is the same, and if not, it goes to a routine to handle the update of the data before running the main application. The routine (methods) are coded in the updated version of the code and know how to handle the version change (re-download, convert existing, etc.).  Or am I missing your point?

Comment: Right - and the routine to handle updating the data needs to somehow determine if it needs to update the data.  I'm saying to use a file format version constant to see if it needs to update the data - if the data has that file format in it or it's in a path by that format version, then keep it or redownload it.

Comment: Is there a downside to the way I handle versioning?  I'm asking out of curiosity, not trying to be rude.  I would think that an app update would be able to have the update version method modified with a new 'else if' check to compare versions and handle updates accordingly.  Maybe my way has a downside i'm missing?

Comment: Can you recommend any online examples of your method of versioning?

Comment: @Javy: both will ultimately work. What I've found is that switching on versions tends to be problematic.  For example, I see folks switch on the version to determine if they should call an API instead of going to the truth (check if implements).  In the same way, I see folks check version to determine how they access a database etc... instead of maintaining a protocol version.  Ultimately I always try to decouple decisions from version and based it on the truth - the files version, the API.  I've seen protocols/APIs/data come and go over versions so then you're checking in a range ... wierd.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4930/discussion-between-javy-and-bryanmac)

Answer (score 0):

It's always a good practice to get the version of your app from the bundle in code and perform necessary changes as needed:

```
NSString* versionString = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:(NSString *)kCFBundleVersionKey];
```

Then you can compare this string (or float version of the string) to determine what changes to make to the data.  You might delete the old data (as in your case), or extract some of the old data and create new data (the usual way), or the app may need no changes at all.

The BIG thing to keep in mind is you may upload/release several versions of an app and some users may not have downloaded the newer versions.  Because of this, it's good practice to have methods update the data based on the version string, instead of expecting it to be the last version of the data.

Comment: The downside to using the appVersion is the appVersion changes much more frequently than your file format changes (bug fixes for example).  This will cause the user to needlessly redownload the files if you fix a binary bug.  The two are different and don't need to be coupled.

Comment: But the code can tell it not not download if it's a simple bug fix.  if( version == 2.02 ) // don't download / change data, only update data version number

Comment: You shouldn't determine if the data needs to be updated based in incidental data like the version and building big switch blocks.  Let the data define if it needs to be updated.  If the data has the file format version (or stored in path by file format version) that's the truth and what defines if it needs to be updated.